Configuration in task.json and launch.json in Vs Code for showing execution time in terminal after running
I am a complete beginner in this, with the help of Chatgpt i configured my task.json and launch.json (i have no idea what are they), the programs are running fine but the terminal is not showing execution time, without knowing my code execution time i wont be able to optimize it (As i want to practise for competitive Programming). Below is my task.json and launch.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}", 
                "shell": { 
                    "executable": "/bin/bash", 
                    "args": [ 
                        "-c" 
                    ] 
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}

launch.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clang build active file (C)",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "detail": "Compiling C file with Clang"
        },
        {
            "label": "clang++ build active file (C++)",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "detail": "Compiling C++ file with Clang"
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang - Build and run active file (C)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang build active file (C)",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb"
        }
    ]
}

I want it to be configured so that it shows my code execution time and, while coding in any language(C or c++) i do not have to manually change the compiler every time.

"i want to practise for competitive Programming" ... then, possibly (depends on the kind of competition), you don't need the program running time, just the time to write, test, and debug your code :-)

Honestly I have to wonder why you used ChatGpt instead of the official documentation. At the very least it would have told you what tasks.json and launch.json are for, not to mention being more reliable.

Your launch.json file is garbage. In fact it looks like a tasks.json file, I guess ChatGPT doesn't know the difference. Honestly if you want to be a programmer you are going to have to get used to reading documentation.

Your tasks.json file is confused over which compiler you have, but maybe you have several, who knows.

i did try to read it but it was way too long and i just wanted to start my coding journey @john

@anand And now you are asking here. Unfortunately it's often the case that if you rush ahead without any understanding it ends up taking longer than if you had gone more slowly. I am not trying to discourage you, but programming is hard, C++ is hard, VSCode is hard (there are easier alternatives). Be realistic about how much you can achieve and how quickly.

@anand To answer your question frankly, I would ignore this issue for now. The priority for you must be to get a working platform in which you can do any coding at all, before worrying about timing and optimizing your code. Revisit this issue when you have a bit more understanding.

thank you for taking the time to read it, i will surely take your advice @john

I have written this guide Setup Guide for C/C++ Programming on VSCode in which I explain on a very basic level how the tasks.json and launch.json can be used. Maybe it will help. Basically tasks.json will perform any CLI command you ask of it. So you can find a CLI utility like this to measure execution time and use it in tasks.
